# Need meta box only on create post not in edit post

Tags: php, wordpress, meta-boxes

I have used this code which appears on both add & edit post

```
<?php

/**
 * Adds a box to the main column on the Post and Page edit screens.
 */
function myplugin_add_meta_box() {

    $screens = array( 'post', 'page' );

    foreach ( $screens as $screen ) {

        add_meta_box(
            'myplugin_sectionid',
            __( 'My Post Section Title', 'myplugin_textdomain' ),
            'myplugin_meta_box_callback',
            $screen
        );
    }
}
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'myplugin_add_meta_box' );

/**
 * Prints the box content.
 * 
 * @param WP_Post $post The object for the current post/page.
 */
function myplugin_meta_box_callback( $post ) {

    // Add an nonce field so we can check for it later.
    wp_nonce_field( 'myplugin_meta_box', 'myplugin_meta_box_nonce' );

    /*
     * Use get_post_meta() to retrieve an existing value
     * from the database and use the value for the form.
     */
    $value = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_my_meta_value_key', true );

    echo '<label for="myplugin_new_field">';
    _e( 'Description for this field', 'myplugin_textdomain' );
    echo '</label> ';
    echo '<input type="text" id="myplugin_new_field" name="myplugin_new_field" value="' . esc_attr( $value ) . '" size="25" />';
}

/**
 * When the post is saved, saves our custom data.
 *
 * @param int $post_id The ID of the post being saved.
 */
function myplugin_save_meta_box_data( $post_id ) {

    /*
     * We need to verify this came from our screen and with proper authorization,
     * because the save_post action can be triggered at other times.
     */

    // Check if our nonce is set.
    if ( ! isset( $_POST['myplugin_meta_box_nonce'] ) ) {
        return;
    }

    // Verify that the nonce is valid.
    if ( ! wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['myplugin_meta_box_nonce'], 'myplugin_meta_box' ) ) {
        return;
    }

    // If this is an autosave, our form has not been submitted, so we don't want to do anything.
    if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) {
        return;
    }

    // Check the user's permissions.
    if ( isset( $_POST['post_type'] ) && 'page' == $_POST['post_type'] ) {

        if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_page', $post_id ) ) {
            return;
        }

    } else {

        if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ) ) {
            return;
        }
    }

    /* OK, it's safe for us to save the data now. */

    // Make sure that it is set.
    if ( ! isset( $_POST['myplugin_new_field'] ) ) {
        return;
    }

    // Sanitize user input.
    $my_data = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['myplugin_new_field'] );

    // Update the meta field in the database.
    update_post_meta( $post_id, '_my_meta_value_key', $my_data );
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'myplugin_save_meta_box_data' );
```

I am making a push notification to be sent while creating a new post by making a checkbox to check when to send push notification. But while editing the post, that meta box stays there. So I want to remove that meta box while editing the post.

Comment: Please explain what you expect, what works and doesn't, etc. What did you try ?

Comment: I am making a push notification to be sent while creating a new post. By making a check box to check when to send push notification. But while editing post that meta box stays there which makes confusion there. So I want to remove that meta box while editing the post. Got my point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [load-(page) action hook](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/load-(page)). In your case, change this line:

```
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'myplugin_add_meta_box' );
```

to this line:

```
function load_post_new_meta_boxes() {
    add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'myplugin_add_meta_box' );
}
add_action("load-post-new.php", "load_post_new_meta_boxes");
```